# Internal linked pages count in Google Search Console (GSC) does not add up

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, search-engine-indexing, internal-links

I have an e-commerce site which has approx. 2500 pages most of which are e-commerce products page. There are approx. 50 pages which are static pages and rest of the pages are dynamic and all the content is dynamic too. These dynamic pages include (categories, subcategories and product pages).

The website has a hierarchal structure for example: home page, categories page -> sub-categories page -> products page and so on.

I assume the top level pages (home, all the product category pages) should have highest amount of internal links as they are at the top of the hierarchy tree but that is not the case. The GSC (Google Search Console) shows some product pages having high number of internal links and most of the category pages (high values pages) have less number of internal links.

How is this possible?
How can I find what is causing this?

If I can figure out what leads to such internal links result I can work on improving internal links for top level pages.